# Remember/cache 'user role' for portal: how to configure?

Tags: 7

I plan on setting up a different 'portal' for each user type, i.e. Student, Staff Member, etc. I want to prompt the user to select which type they are, and then cache that info in the future so that they don't have to select their type every time. The next time they go to my website, they are shown (redirected to?) their specific portal with links/info pertinent to them. The portal should contain a full menu structure, which may be different for each user type, but a lot of the content will be the same for multiple user types.

I don't want users to have to log in, so using roles within Drupal doesn't make sense. How can I go about doing this? I am planning on adding a taxonomy field to each node to specify which user types the node applies to so perhaps something with that?

This is Drupal 7, and use of existing modules is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with some javascript on your home page. By default, the page would be your select your type form. This could be a manually created form that call JS to create a Cookie with the user's choice. This should be hidden by default.

When a user comes to the site, if they do not have the cookie, show the form. If they have the cookie set, redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try this.